# using VScode, trying to link to an asset but two characters in the link are yellow rather than orange ... why?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4

[image: screenshot of odd colored letters]

i'm also using a bootstrap cdn in here .. could that be why?
it was an easy fix, but im still curious.
was it because i copy and pasted it?

Comment: A backslash is an escape character and has a special meaning combined with the next character (m). e.g. `\n` is a new line. You probably want to use a forward slash here. VSCode detects this for you and indicates it with another color.

Comment: html/css does not use \ as directory separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode helps you identify errors with color coding. Your url might be wrong. Try (“assets/mechanic-logo.png”)

Comment: yeah, I just went back to look and see what I did. using a forward slash was indeed the fix. Thanks for pointing it out for me!!! Otherwise I wouldn't have noticed.